# ROS Node for computation

Tags: ros-lunar, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to understand the ROS Computation graph. I understand that we can have nodes such as a camera, a servo motor, an ultrasonic sensor, or an esc. These nodes publish their messages to topics which may come back to the master or go to other notes. I feel silly asking this, but where do you do the computation? Where do you take all these inputs, calculate and output a resulting value?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284499/ros-node-for-computation/) by [surya](https://answers.ros.org/users/34019/surya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> where do you do the computation? Where do you take all these inputs, calculate and output a resulting value?

in other nodes, that get their data from the 'camera', 'servo motor' and 'ultrasonic sensor' nodes.

Nodes that interact with (hardware) devices are typicall called drivers.

The other nodes implement your business logic.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0